# How to print all non-environment variables?

Tags: variable

How to print all non-environment variables?

These are all the variables I've added myself since the moment the shell started, like when doing:

```
read abc
    123
# echo ${abc} => 123
```

Or

```
xyz='123'
# echo ${xyz} => 123
```

I want to print all of them, to know what was added to the memory, so I could clean it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Bash, this command will list the names of all shell variables that are not inherited by a child process and not part of the default slate:

```
diff -U 1 <(set -o posix ; set |cut -d= -f1) <(exec bash -ic 'set -o posix ; set' | cut -d= -f1)|grep '^[-][^-]'|cut -d- -f2|grep -vE '^(COLUMNS|HISTFILESIZE|HISTSIZE|LINES|PIPESTATUS)$'
```

This produces a list of all variable names in the current shell (with [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)), and a list of all variable names in a newly-created subprocess running the same shell, finds all those present in the first list and not the second (with [`diff`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html), the last cut, and the first grep), and trims out some Bash-specific default variables that the subprocess won't have because it's not a user-facing shell. `set -o posix` makes `set` list only the variables and not functions.

It will omit *both* inherited environment variables and variables you've explicitly marked for export.

Swap out `bash` for your shell. You'll also need to change the list of ignored variables in the last `grep`, and can probably lose `set -o posix`. If your shell doesn't have [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), you'll need to use temporary files instead, or platform-specific access to file descriptors (like `/dev/fd`).

---

On the other hand, if all you want to do is clear out your own local variables and functions then

```
exec bash
```

will have that effect (while also re-reading some configuration files and potentially losing local changes to shell options).